# Wrong year format for pd.to_datetime format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Using pandas, I have a dataframe with column 'REPAIR_YEAR' values listed such as:

```
2018
2018
2019
2020
2021
```

I want to set this to a year value, so I run

```
df['REPAIR_YEAR'] = pd.to_datetime(df['REPAIR_YEAR'])
```

Instead of 2018, 2019, 2020, o2 2021, the result is:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002018
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002018
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002019
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002020
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002021
```

How can I make the results show the correct year and not 1970?

Comment: so you are trying to get values like this `2018-01-01`,`2019-01-01`?

Comment: whats day and month of expected output?

Comment: Thank you for asking. I only have data on the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`format="%Y"`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

```
df["REPAIR_YEAR"] = pd.to_datetime(df["REPAIR_YEAR"], format="%Y")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  REPAIR_YEAR
0  2018-01-01
1  2018-01-01
2  2019-01-01
3  2020-01-01
4  2021-01-01
```